# Как изменить картинку кнопки через tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Допустим я  нажимаю на кнопку и она должна поменять картинку

Comment: Добрый день! В вашем вопросе не хватает примера минимального кода с проблемой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `PhotoImage` чтобы загрузить картинку и параметр `image` у кнопки, чтобы установить ей картинку.

[Пример загружает картинки в список](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/d9aac8318c5753428f39552e9432360100d8c44f/tkinter_examples/button__change_button_icon_on_click) и при клике на кнопку меняет ей иконку на следующую в списке:

```
import tkinter as tk

def _on_button_click(button):
    global PHOTO_COUNTER
    PHOTO_COUNTER += 1
    if len(photo_list) <= PHOTO_COUNTER:
        PHOTO_COUNTER = 0

    button.config(image=photo_list[PHOTO_COUNTER])


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

PHOTO_COUNTER = 0

photo_list = [
    tk.PhotoImage(file="icons/ok.png"),
    tk.PhotoImage(file="icons/no.png"),
    tk.PhotoImage(file="icons/help.png"),
]

button = tk.Button(root, text="ClickMe!", image=photo_list[PHOTO_COUNTER])
button.config(command=lambda: _on_button_click(button))
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.** вариант с `PHOTO_COUNTER` можно упростить за счет использования генератора:

```
import tkinter as tk


def _on_button_click(button):
    button.config(image=get_next_image())


def next_image_generator():
    photo_list = [
        tk.PhotoImage(file="icons/ok.png"),
        tk.PhotoImage(file="icons/no.png"),
        tk.PhotoImage(file="icons/help.png"),
    ]

    while True:
        yield from photo_list


NEXT_IMAGE = next_image_generator()

def get_next_image():
    return next(NEXT_IMAGE)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

button = tk.Button(root, text="ClickMe!", image=get_next_image())
button.config(command=lambda: _on_button_click(button))
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь